# Raic controller with ext sata cage

Tags: hard-drive, raid, storage, nas, sata

I was wondering how difficult it is to create a Raid 5 system on an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop pc already running. I plan to use [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816124028&cm_re=raid_controller_card-_-16-124-028-_-Product) Raid card with [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817121913&utm_medium=Email&utm_source=IGNEFL110615&cm_mmc=EMC-IGNEFL110615-_-EMC-110615-Index-_-ServerAccessories-_-17121913-S1A7C) Sata Cage and add 4 HDD for backup and storage.

I need to have previous back ups available so I need quite a bit of storage space.

I looked at the NAS system but because it's only one PC, I don't want to spend a lot of money.